# Register javascript function after AJAX load (using UpdatePanel)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

In an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` (in my ASP.NET (4.0) web application) I have both HTML and javascript variables/functions... for example, something along the lines of this...

Note that the javascript/HTML is only to be displayed when the UpdatePanel is updated via an AJAX update... it is not displayed on initial page load

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="udpMyPanel">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <%If Page.IsPostBack Then%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var myVar = "<%=CodeBehindVariable.ToString()%>";
      function myFnc() {
        ...
      }
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFnc();return false;">Hello World</a>
    <%End If%>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that when the UpdatePage AJAX is loaded, the javascript within the panel is not available to the browser... so calling `myFnc()` doesn't work, because the function isn't registered.  Nor the `myVar` variable.

Without putting the entire script into a string, and registering it with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` in the codebehind, is there any way to register this mark-up based javascript once the panel has been loaded by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's not nice, it's not pretty, but this works...

Firstly, I've wrapped the javascript in a `<asp:Panel>` element.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="udpMyPanel">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <%If Page.IsPostBack Then%>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlJavascript">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = "<%=CodeBehindVariable.ToString()%>";
        function myFnc() {
          ...
        }
      </script>
    </asp:Panel>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFnc();return false;">Hello World</a>
    <%End If%>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then on the `PreRender` in the code behind, I've captured the contents of the panel, removed the HTML tags, and registered it as script.  Then the panel has been hiden as there is no point that being passed to the browser.

```
   Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        Dim sManager As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me.Page)
        If sManager IsNot Nothing AndAlso sManager.IsInAsyncPostBack Then
            ' If AJAX postback, hide the DIV and use its content as the
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            pnlJavascript.RenderControl(New HtmlTextWriter(New System.IO.StringWriter(sb)))
            Dim script As String = sb.ToString()

            ' Remove div tags (generated from the panel)
            Dim startTag As String = String.Format("<div id=""{0}"">", pnlJavascript.ClientID)
            script = script.Replace(startTag, "").Replace("</div>", "")

            ' Remove script tags
            script = script.Replace("<script type=""text/javascript"">", "").Replace("</script>", "")

            ' Register it
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType(), "registerJS", script, True)

            ' Hide it
            pnlJavascript.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```