# How go I get the javascript in my user control to work inside of a panel whose visibility is false on page load?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I am working on an ASP.NET/C# project in which we are placing a user control into an AJAX panel whose visibility is set to false on page load. The visibility of this panel is set to true once the user submits some parameters. However, although the user control and all of the other panel contents are visible once these parameters are set and submitted, the uc's javascript functions do not work.

I attempted to solve this issue by adding Page.Controls.Add(controlID) in Page_Load if it is not a postback. The functionality is all there when I do this, but I know that there is a better way to get the functionality because in this case the control is being added to the page twice.

EDIT: I put the controller in a div outside of the panel and got the control that I wanted out of it. However, if anyone can explain why the javascript of the control wasn't defined or offer a solution that keeps my UC in the panel, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: visiblity via CSS is just a screen display/document layout thing. the elements and any/all code attached to them still exist in the DOM and are fully accessible-  the user just can't see them. you'd need to show what this code is and how you're attaching your code to that "hidden" stuff.

Comment: Question: have you set Visible = false on the panel or have you hidden it by using css ?

Comment: The control is added in the HTML markup. <uc1:control name /> and, yes, we have set Visible=false to the panel.

What I would like to do is remove the user control from the panel and set its visibility using css.

Comment: Is it an AJAX panel? If it is a regular panel, whose contents are rendered (included the UC) on postback, and the UC's javascript functions are not working, then there's more of an issue than just having the UC in the panel. Have you verified your UC on a separate, test page, where it is rendered initially?

Comment: It is an Ajax panel, and the UC is used on many different pages and works well. 

The reason it is in the panel is because we only want it visible when the panel's other contents are visible, as the UC toggles the visibility of a chart in the panel and uses + or - images to indicate whether it is showing or hiding the chart.

When the UC is moved into a div outside of the panel (very easy to control visibility using css here), the + and - images do not always correspond to whether or not the graph is being displayed.

Comment: Loading the javascript via an AJAX call is the critical piece of info here, and makes your question very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228291/register-javascript-function-after-ajax-load-using-updatepanel). Try the solution there, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

If for asp server control the visible property is set to false, then that control is not even rendered on the page. Since the User Control is inside the ajax server control, the user control is not rendered. Javascript code is executed by the browser hence it must be present on the page to run.
If you can set css property display: none to hide and display: block to show for the ajax server control, then user control and its javascript will be rendered on the page, however hidden from user for css property i set to display: none, so its javascript will be executed.

To set display property of ajax server control, you could use: ajaxControl.Styles.Add("display", "none").
Hope this helps you.